# Does the OpenNI drivers expose Roll Pitch Yaw

Tags: ros, kinect, libopenni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a few RGBD camera's, the Asus Xtrion and the Kinect. I want to know if the ROS OpenNI drivers expose Pose.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217736/does-the-openni-drivers-expose-roll-pitch-yaw/) by [soulslicer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20426/soulslicer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you mean frame used to track user ?
[Openni_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker) can get you differents users with their TF Tree associated.

---

Originally posted by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) with karma: 109 on 2015-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [soulslicer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20426/soulslicer/) on 2015-09-16**:
How exactly do I do that? What I need is the Pitching and Rolling angles of the camera, where the frame of reference is flat ground

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-09-16**:
if I understand well what you mean, you want the frame of the sensor ? I dont think that this kind of sensor have an IMU integrated. You have to calculate it when you track an user (considering that the user is standing still and do some tf maths)